# How to set a default loading animation on android image view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I am using async to load the image into a grid view / list view. For each place download the image for internet , I use a class to handle it. The problem is , how to set a loading icon on it (at the center of the image view)? Thanks

The imageloader class:

```
public class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

    private static String TAG = "ImageLoader";
    public InputStream input;
    public ImageView view;
    public String imageURL;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {

            view = (ImageView) params[0];
            imageURL = (String) params[1];

            URL url = new URL(imageURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null && view != null) {
            view.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom layout in your `GridView` or `ListView` that is a `RelativeLayout` containing your `ImageView` and a `ProgressBar` for the loading-animation.

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You would then need to pass the `RelativeLayout` to the `AsyncTask` from which you can retreive

a) your `ImageView` and

b) the `ProgressBar`

When the download is complete (e.g. you enter the method `onPostExecute`) you do the following:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    if (result != null && image != null) {
        image.setImageBitmap(result); // change 'image' to the ImageView you retreived earlier from your RelativeLayout
    }
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide the ProgressBar
}
```